# Search Bar moves down after clicking on it (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

There is a code that creates the Search Bar. After there is a click on this Search Bar, then it is shifted down along with the "Cancel" button. I enclose screenshots and code.

[before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EuvN.jpg)

[after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/229fH.jpg)

```
@IBAction func showSearchBar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
   self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([], animated: true)

   self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

   self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self 
   self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self 
   self.searchController.delegate = self

   self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
   self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
   self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
   self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Искать продукты"

   self.searchController.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
   self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal

   self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
   self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I've never used the `UISearchController`, but two things comes to mind. (1) what if `setShowsCancelButton` is false? (2) How do you wish it to behave *without*  cancel button?

Comment: @dfd (1) if setShowsCancelButton is false - again all the same =( (2) I want with cancel button

Comment: Hi, have you solved this?

Comment: @Glenn hi, yes.

Comment: Oh wow. Would you mind answering your own question (this thread), so that it could be considered as closed? I'm sharing mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53264329/3231194

Comment: @Glenn sorry, your problem is very difficult. My problem was very easy.

Comment: I understand. I assume you were just using UISearchBar. :) Thank you!