# UISearchBar Height Automatic Size Change Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

[image: original image]

**The screenshot is taken from iPhone:**

[image: second image]

I'm working on a simple app and adding a programatically UISearchbar but I am really confused about why shows extra space from the top like the second image. but when I write the UISearchbar changes our position like the first image.

**This is my code:**

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
 self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
 self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
 self.searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .black
 self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
 self.definesPresentationContext = true
 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
 navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    }
   }

extension starControl: UISearchBarDelegate{

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){
    //Show Cancel
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
    searchBar.tintColor = .black
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String){

}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    guard let term = searchBar.text , term.isEmpty == false else{
        return
    }
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
    searchBar.text = String()
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
 }
}
```

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this, I've tried to solve this issue but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318022/uisearchbar-increases-navigation-bar-height-in-ios-11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is latest **swift4.2** code and latest functionality of search bar just put this function in controller and call from viewDidLoad.

```
func setupNavBar() {
        self.title = "Controller title"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
```

Comment: Facing Same Problem

Comment: Is your viewController embed with navigation controller? because we are adding search bar controller in navigation bar

Comment: Same height problem

Comment: Simple Show https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0eo5.png
when i am click o https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Etl7.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgL4m.png how to achieve this type of search bar

Comment: You can't remove height because it's for a title, can you add navigation bar title?

Comment: This is the newest implementation by apple, you can add a title as large or small, or Let me check is there any solution!