# Programmatically Show Navigation Bar's UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have configured a `UISearchController` as follows within `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil);
searchController.delegate = self;
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

self.searchController.isActive = true;
self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder();

self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController;
```

Although I have set `isActive` and set the `searchBar` as the `firstResponder`, the UISearchController is not active when the view appears on the screen. Manually tapping on the field opens it correctly.

Is there a reason in iOS 12 that the `isActive` and `becomeFirstResponder` properties are not respected in `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's happening there, but it's unique to the fact it is in the navigation bar.

This seems to do the trick though.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    DispatchQueue.main.async(searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder)
}
```

Comment: No need for weak self when using `DispatchQueue.main.async...` https://stackoverflow.com/a/41992442/3231194

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in iOS 12.x, I just put the `becomeFirstResponder()` in `viewDidAppear`, with a bit of delay, *0.1 seconds*. Adding such delay guarantees presentation of keyboard.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.definesPresentationContext = true

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

EDIT: If you're supporting iOS 10, and 11, this answer of mine from the past might help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53264329/3231194

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but would prefer not to have to delay the execution of the code block.

Comment: It's up to you. That won't freeze the UI and it's the only way, that I know, to present the keyboard of the searchBar.