# UISearchBar is below status bar after rotation (back to portrait mode)

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uistatusbar

Reproduce (bug only with iPhone devices <= 8, works ok with iPhone X* devices):

1. Open search bar (by clicking search item on top bar) in portrait mode

`@IBAction func onSearchBarItemClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}`

[image]

2. Rotate device to landscape position

[image]

3. Rotate back to portrait position

[image]

Now it's below status bar and it overlaps the content at the bottom

How can I fix it?

UISearchController:

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.asciiCapable
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

**Update**

Sample Project: https://github.com/anonym24/SearchBarBelowStatusBar/

Comment: I have tested your above code in simulator it seems to work fine, pre and post rotation. Can you share your complete source code?

Comment: I did it on iPhone 7

Comment: @Deepak https://github.com/anonym24/SearchBarBelowStatusBar/

Comment: @Deepak run this app, click search bar item, don't close search bar, rotate to landscape with "alt+left" and then again to portrait with "alt+right"

Comment: @Deepak did you test the sample project?

Comment: yes, I did. It's because of the navigationBar. Not able to resolve yet. You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318022/uisearchbar-increases-navigation-bar-height-in-ios-11 [  Workaround:You can use default searchBarController for navigationItem: navigationItem.searchController = searchController   ]

Comment: @Deepak they say with this workaround it puts the search bar below the navigation