# NavigationItem does not return to its original size after removing the UISearchController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

A clone of Candy Search from the Wenderlich folks. I added an icon to show/hide the search bar.

However, after removing the search controller from the navigationItem, the nav bar does not return to its original size.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I've tried of few things but none of them worked.

`self.searchController.isActive = false` didn't make any difference.

One more thing, at this point of frustration, if you now click on a row to instantiate a detail controller and come back, the nav bar is back to normal height!

Thanks!

See screenshot:

[image: screenshot of showing/hiding the UISearchbar]

Full project here: https://github.com/HerrDoktorBD/CVSearch

Relevant code:

```
lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Candy"

    // scope bar
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [
        "All",
        "Chocolate",
        "Hard",
        "Other"
    ]

    return searchController
}()
```

```
func showSearchBar(show: Bool) {

    let sb: UISearchBar = searchController.searchBar

    if show {
        //print("show searchbar")

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: .curveEaseOut,
                       animations: {

            if #available(iOS 13, *) {
                self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
            }

        }, completion: { (status) in

            sb.becomeFirstResponder()
        })
    }
    else {
        //print("hide searchbar")

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: .curveEaseOut,
                       animations: {

            sb.resignFirstResponder()

        }, completion: { (status) in

            if #available(iOS 13, *) {
                self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to update layout. [self.view.layoutIfNeeded()]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it did not help. I also tried ```self.view.setNeedsLayout()``` which scoots the tableview up but the navigationItem height still won't reset. We're getting close...

Comment: I found this on an another stack post.
    navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
    navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
m8 work check this ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318022/uisearchbar-increases-navigation-bar-height-in-ios-11

Comment: That works. I had to call ```@objc func forceNavHeightReset() {
        self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }``` with ```self.perform(#selector(self.forceNavHeightReset),
                             with: nil,
                             afterDelay: 0.1)```. Updated github repo. Thank you so much.

Comment: can i add this as answer will  you upvote ?

Comment: Certainly. But I don't have enough points.

Comment: fine! happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update navigation view's height instead

```
navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout() 
navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

happy codding !